# Unable to build Bitcoin on Mac Catalina

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling

I keep getting this error message after running 'make' or 'make check':

```
Making check in src
  CXXLD    bitcoind
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN2Db6verifyEPKcS1_PSoj", referenced from:
      __ZN16BerkeleyDatabase6VerifyER13bilingual_str in libbitcoin_wallet.a(libbitcoin_wallet_a-bdb.o)
  "__ZN5boost10filesystem4path5imbueERKSt6locale", referenced from:
      __Z16SetupEnvironmentv in libbitcoin_util.a(libbitcoin_util_a-system.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bitcoind] Error 1
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: How did you install Berkeley-DB? What compiler are you using to build Core?

Comment: I installed Berkeley-DB using brew (brew install berkeley-db4) and am using gcc-10. I had to explicitly configure like this though because compiling C++ on Catalina is a pain: './configure CXX=g++-10 CPP=cpp-10 CC=gcc-10'

Comment: I don't think setting CPP is needed. I set the variables with `export` in `~/.zprofile` and configure automatically takes them from the env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berkeley-db from brew which is clang compiled is GCC incompatible. Either Recompile berkeley-db4 with GCC:

`HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-10 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-10 brew reinstall --build-from-source berkeley-db4`

or compile Core with clang

Discussion: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3228

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that fixed the Berkeley-DB problem but I just received this error message after running 'make check':    `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN5boost10filesystem4path5imbueERKSt6locale", referenced from:
      __Z16SetupEnvironmentv in libbitcoin_util.a(libbitcoin_util_a-system.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bitcoind] Error 1
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
`.  Any ideas how to fix this one?

Comment: You need to rebuild boost too similarly

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out the command to do that - do you know what it should be?

Comment: Running `HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-10 HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-10 brew install --build-from-source boost --HEAD`   or  `brew install boost --build-from-source --HEAD` leads to the following patch error: `==> Patching
==> Applying 7b3fc734242eea9af734d6cd8ccb3d8f6b64c5b2.patch
patching file boost-install.jam
Hunk #1 FAILED at 483.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file boost-install.jam.rej`

Comment: Remove `--HEAD`

Comment: Just tried and got this error: `==> ./b2 headers
Last 15 lines from /Users/julian_moraes/Library/Logs/Homebrew/boost/02.b2:
* rule clang.init-cxxstd-flags ( toolset : condition * : version )
* called with: ( clang-darwin : <toolset>clang :  )
* missing argument version
/private/tmp/boost-20210316-2413-8781zu/boost_1_75_0/tools/build/src/tools/clang.jam:54:see definition of rule 'clang.init-cxxstd-flags' being called
/private/tmp/boost-20210316-2413-8781zu/boost_1_75_0/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:44: in toolset.using
/private/tmp/boost-20210316-2413` .. It continues for a bit after

Comment: Not sure why clang is being used so would appreciate any additional insights. Thanks a bunch for the help!